# Extracting Text from only QLineEdit widgets in a QGridLayout in pyqt4

Tags: python, text, pyqt4

I have a QGrid Layout with around 15 widgets consisting of QLabels , QLineEdits and QComboBoxes. I would like a function which extracts the text from only the QLineEdit widgets.

What I mean is something like this

```
for i in range(self.grid.count()):
    if self.grid.itemAt.widget(i).Type == QtGui.QLineEdit: //Not able to figure out the syntax 
        print self.grid.itemAt.widget(i).text()
```

Could someone help out with the syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong syntax for `itemAt`. Try this:

```
    from PyQt4.QtGui import *
    ...
    for i in range(self.grid.count()):
        w = self.grid.itemAt(i).widget()
        print isinstance(w, QLineEdit)
```

It should work just fine.